# How to return sparse matrix from CUSP::csr_matrix in MEX to Matlab?

Tags: matlab, return, sparse-matrix, mex, cusp-library

I am developing my MEX file for sparse matrix computing with CUDA. I am using CUSP library. I don't know how to return cusp::csr_matrix back to Matlab. For example, I have

```
cusp::csr_matrix<mwIndex,double,cusp::host_memory> At(m,n,N);
```

So, it is At matrix in CSR format, which, lets say, I have computed. Now, I have to return it to Matlab. Something like this:

```
plhs[0] = At;
```

But, of course, it doesn't work like that, firstly because At is on GPU. I guess I should use At.values and methods for indexes. But, also, how to assign them to host data?

Could somebody suggest how to do all that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab stores sparse matrices in CSR format too, so it's not complicated. All you have to do is to allocate the sparse matrix using `mxArray *mxCreateSparse(mwSize m, mwSize n, mwSize nzmax, mxComplexity ComplexFlag);` and then setting the pr, ir, jc arrays (using `mxGetPr`, `mxGetIr`, `mxGetJc`). Pr corresponds to the values array in cusp, ir to column_indices and jc to row_offsets. If the matrix is in device memory, copy it using `cudaMemcpy` with  `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost`. [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Sparse-Matrices-with-Mex_002dFiles.html) is some examples using sparse matrices (its for Octave, but should work for Matlab as well).

Comment: Thank you. In addition, what I figured out, Thrust can be used for that in case of using CUSP. For example, device vector Xg can be returned to Matlab array T like that: mxArray *T = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, 1, mxREAL); double *x = mxGetPr(T); thrust::copy(xg.begin(), xg.end(), x);